# libgdx and box2d, screen touch coordinates nonsensical

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I have a simple box2d world with a platform and camera tracking the player. i'm trying to get touch input control when i touch a side of the screen, yet it feels more complicated than i think it is. touching the screen occasionally moves the box but never when i hit the spot i expect, and trying to debug by drawing a picture where i touch has only led to more confusion. here's all the code with the camera or touch listening

create method

```
    public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new MyInputProcessor());

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, w/2, h/2);

    touchpos = new Vector3();

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), false);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    player = createBox(8, 10, 32, 32, false);
    platform = createBox(0, 0, 64, 32, true);
}
```

render method

```
    public void render () {
    update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    b2dr.render(world, camera.combined.scl(PPM)); 
}
```

resize

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width / 2, height / 2);
}
```

camera update

```
    public void cameraUpdate(float delta){
    Vector3 position = camera.position;
    position.x = player.getPosition().x * PPM;
    position.y = player.getPosition().y * PPM;
    camera.position.set(position);

    camera.update();
}
```

touch input method and math

```
    @Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    touchpos.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
    camera.unproject(touchpos);

    if (touchpos.x > 500){
        touchleft = true;
    }
    else touchleft = false;

    if (touchpos.x < 300){
        touchright = true;
    }
    else touchright = false;

    if (300 < touchpos.x && touchpos.x < 500){
        touchcenter = true;
    }
    else touchcenter = false;

    return true;
}
```

I think it should be as simple as using the raw touch values without messing with the camera as i want the areas used for control to be the same always but that didn't work, so i took to google and tried unprojecting and doing other fiddling with the camera but the touch has never worked.

i feel like the answer should be simple. all i need is that when it detects a touch in the left or right of the screen for it to set the appropriate variable to true

if anyone with more experience can see the error i'd super appreciate

Answer (score 1):

scl() transform Matrix4(camera.combined) value so don't scale camera.combined.

```
float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
camera = new OrthographicCamera(30, 30 * (h / w));

 public void render () {
    update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    b2dr.render(world, camera.combined); 
}
```

You are going to work with physics so Keep the size of moving objects roughly between 0.1 and 10 meters, not greater then 10.

If you want to draw images just scale box2d dimension by 30 and get dimension  in pixels.

And for touch, you're setting viewport according to device width and height and applying condition on predefined value.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    touchpos.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
    camera.unproject(touchpos);

    if (touchpos.x > camera.viewportWidth*.8f){
        touchleft = true;
    }
    else touchleft = false;

    if (touchpos.x < camera.viewportWidth*.2f){
        touchright = true;
    }
    else touchright = false;

    if (camera.viewportWidth*.2f< touchpos.x && touchpos.x < camera.viewportWidth*.8f){
        touchcenter = true;
    }
    else touchcenter = false;

    return true;
}
```